# Algebraic topology-Deformation retraction

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be space, and $X=U\cup V$, $U,V$ be two arbitary sets. $A\subset U$ and $A$ is deformation retraction of $U$, then can we way $A\cup V$ is deformation retraction of $X$?(Let the element of $V$ fixed during the deformation).

Comment: The core in this problem is that does the desired "deformation retraction" continuous? Since it can't use pasting Lemma, and the direct proof does't seem to be obvious.

Comment: It arises in the proof of Theorem 72.1 in James Topology. It just says "extend this deformation retraction to all U\time I (In that proof, U is total space) letting each point of A (A is not what we say in this question) fixed during the deformation". But I am confused since how can we know it is continuous??

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of the proof of theorem 72.1?  When I try searching for James Topology, all I can find is the book by Munkres.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $X=(-1,2)\cup(1,3)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. Then $\{0\}$ is a deformation retract of $(-1,2)$, but $\{0\}\cup(1,3)$ is not a deformation retract of $X$, because it is disconnected and $X$ is not.